# Is this regular expression simplification correct?

Tags: regex

I was reading the "How Browsers Work" article here: [How Browsers Work](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/internals/howbrowserswork/) (It's a great read.)

But at one point, they mention this as a rule of their grammar defining an integer:

```
INTEGER :0|[1-9][0-9]*
```

Is it, or is it not, exactly the same (and simpler) to write:

```
INTEGER :[1-9]*[0-9]
```

I couldn't think of a case that did not satisfy both rules, nor a reason why the first rule would be preferred.

Is there a reason for including a simple base case (such as `0`), or is it just pedantics?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These two expressions are different: the first one will take `101`, but the second one wouldn't. The expression from the book is pretty good at matching integers while disallowing leading zeros.

Comment: You get the accept for beating me by 30 seconds, and a congratulatory upvote for somehow picking the same test input as I did. :)

Answer (score 2):

They are not the same, as my simplification can only include one zero, and only if it is a trailing zero. Eg. this case does not match for the simplified rule:

```
101
```

Comment: That's funny - we both picked `101` for an example :)